# iphone and Gmail

Tags: iphone, gmail

When sending an Gmail email from my iPhone with Gmail as the default account those who receive my email have it show up in their in-box identified as "GMAIL", not from my email address or identifying me.   What do i need to change for email recipients to see the email is from me?

Answer (score 1):

I found some key videos that show how [your setup should look like:](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uQ22euWXYog)

If all else fails, delete the setup and re-add it following the instructions [here on Google](http://support.google.com/a/users/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=138740).

Good Luck!